# Android welcomes Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

[Hello Stack Overflow](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+blogspot/hsDu+(Android+Developers+Blog))

Android Developers blog have announced that Stack Overflow will be the preferred channel to get newbie questions to android:

> I'm happy to announce that we're working with Stack Overflow to improve developer support, especially for developers new to Android

Is this is some kind of milestone or what?

Congratulations to the Stack Overflow team!!!

Comment: It's too bad Google App engine choose Reddit though. :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cool!

[image]